# MVC bind different entity than view's model

Tags: model-view-controller, submit, models

In our project we are accessing a "Contract" entity through an "InterviewForm" entity in a view. So the view's model is "InterviewForm" and the contract is accessed with Model.Contract.
This view we have is currently a Details view, with the contract details as addition.

A user is supposed to be able to leave a comment at the bottom and press submit. This commentary is saved in the Comment property of the contract.
When pressing Submit, we want to bind the commentary to the Contract entity. However, the Submit button only binds the view's model (InterviewForm).
How do we go about Posting this comment to the Contract entity with the use of a Submit button?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your Comments text box as below, it should automatically bind it to the InterviewForm.Contract.Comment, and I am assuming your Model is InterviewForm.

@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Contract.Comment)